# How to set the fixed value for the create/edit form field in Flask-Admin

Tags: python, flask, flask-admin

I'm using Flask-Admin and Flask-Security to write a website. I want to implement a function: The user which has admin role only can create user which is foo role. The user which has foo role only can create user which is bar role.

I have tried the `QueryAjaxModelLoader`:

```
form_ajax_refs = {
    roles: QueryAjaxModelLoader（"role", db.session, Role, fileds=["name"]）
```

and `form_choices`:

```
form_choices = {"roles": [(3, "foo"), ]}
```

These two methods don't solve the problem. Can anyone give me some advice?

Comment: I choose to override the `on_model_change` method to achieve my purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first, I use `on_model_change` to set the default value of the `roles` field.

And then, I use `form_args` and `query_factory` to limit the choices of `roles` field.

```
def filter_func():
    return db.session.query(Role).filter_by(name="applicant")

form_args = {
    "roles": {
        "query_factory": filter_func
    }
}
```